# WHERE com datas

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho esse SQL que criar grupo com as vendas sempre que tive duas vendas do mesmo cliente no TIPO = 1 e outra no TIPO = 2, ambos concluídas no mês atual.

Só que agora alem disso, o que eu preciso é filtrar as vendas ​​que com TIPO = 2 no mês atual que a outra venda desse cliente no TIPO= 1 pode ser qualquer outro mês não apenas no mês atual.

Atualmente mostra como este: EX cliente = 100 tipo1 data de conclusão = 2017-01 data de conclusão = 2017-01

Preciso que fique assim : EX cliente = 100 tipo1 data de conclusão = 20176-12 ou 2017-01 tipo2 = data de conclusão = 2017-01

Resumido: A data da venda no TIPO =2 deve sempre ser a data do mês atual e data do TIPO = 1 pode ser qualquer mês incluindo o atual.

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE status = 'CONCLUÍDA' and data_conclusao LIKE '2017-01%' and tipo IN ('1', '2') GRUPO by vendas HAVING MIN (tipo) = '1' and MAX (tipo) = '2'
```

**BANCO:**

```
CREATE TABLE `vendas` (
   `Id` int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `cliente` int (11) NOT NULL,
   `Tipo` varchar (15) NOT NULL,
   `produto` varchar (150) NOT NULL,
   `data_conclusao` date NOT NULL
   `status` int (11);
   PRIMARY KEY (`id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=549 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Se você quiser, pode usar as funções de data do MySQL. `MONTH(data_conclusao)  = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(data_conclusao) = YEAR(CURDATE())`, assim, você vai sempre ter a data atual sem precisar ficar trocando o `2017-01%`

Comment: *Now I gotta a question, yo*: qual a estrutura do seu banco de dados ou tabela? Quais os campos que devem ser levados em consideração na consulta?

Comment: @Not The Real Hemingway pronto adicionei a estrutura do banco.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway Resumido: O campo data_conclusao no TIPO =2 deve sempre ser a data do mês atual e data do TIPO = 1 pode ser qualquer mês incluindo o atual.

Comment: @BonfimJunior apresente um resultado tabular atual e o qual você deseja. Assim você esclarece melhor a questão para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tenho uma ideia:

```
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE status = 'CONCLUÍDA' AND (CASE WHEN tipo = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN data_conclusao LIKE '2017-01%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE data_conclusao END)
```

Não foi testada a query. Qualquer edição é bem vinda!